# How to resolve the checkout null issue which is showing in Shopify GraphQL Checkout response

Tags: swift, graphql

I am working on shopify project with GraphQL/Storefront SDK. Currently I am facing checkout response issue. As per documentation I have create input, query and finally NSURLSession Task. The query executes but the response for checkout and error both are showing null. I can't understand what's going wrong in the input.

Here is the code snippet:

```
let inputCheckout = Storefront.CheckoutCreateInput.create(
   email: .value(Preferences.value(forKey: "CustomerEmail") as? String),
   lineItems: .value(lineItems),
   shippingAddress: .value(nil),
   note: .value("This is a testing notes"),
   customAttributes: .value(nil),
   allowPartialAddresses: .value(true)
)
```

Now I am creating mutation:

```
 let mutation = Storefront.buildMutation {$0
            .checkoutCreate(input: inputCheckout) { $0
                .checkout { $0
                    .webUrl()
                }
                .userErrors { $0
                    .field()
                    .message()
                }
            }
        }
```

and then

```
 let task = kAppDelegate.client.mutateGraphWith(mutation) { response, error in

       print("error = \(error.debugDescription)")
       print("response = \(response?.checkoutCreate?.fields)")

  }
  task.resume()
```

And here is response:

```
error = nil
response = Optional(["checkout": <null>, "userErrors": <__NSArray0 0x604000008960>(

)
])
```

No error showing....also no response.... I searched a lot but no solution I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of hit and trial cases, I got the answer:

Only need to replace this method params:

```
let inputCheckout = Storefront.CheckoutCreateInput.create(
   email: .value(Preferences.value(forKey: "CustomerEmail") as? String),
   lineItems: .value(lineItems),
   shippingAddress: .value(nil),
   note: .value("This is a testing notes"),
   customAttributes: .value(nil),
   allowPartialAddresses: .value(true)
)
```

With this one:

```
let inputCheckout = Storefront.CheckoutCreateInput.create(
   lineItems: .value(lineItems),
   allowPartialAddresses: .value(true)
)
```

And now the response is getting correct without any issue.